# Lua resty_dogstatsd only publishes first instance

Tags: lua, datadog

I have a metric client that looks something like:

```
package.path = package.path .. ';../?.lua'

local metrics = {}

local resty_dogstatsd = require('resty_dogstatsd')
local logger = require('module.utils.logger')
local _statsd = resty_dogstatsd.new({
    statsd = {
        host = config.dataDog.host,
        port = config.dataDog.port,
        namespace = config.dataDog.namespace
    },
    tags = config.dataDog.tags
})

function metrics.incMetric1 ()
    logger.debug('Updating metric metric1');

    _statsd:increment(metric1 1, 1)
end

return metrics;
```

Then in my application I import it and use it

```
local metrics = require('module.metrics')

-- somewhere, some condition
metrics.incMetric1()
```

This publishes the log `Updating metric metric1` in datadog and I can see it. But this will only publish the first instance. Until I restart `service nginx restart`, I will not get any more increments.

**Update**

So I have a `start.lua` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/start.lua` that is:

```
package.path = package.path .. ';/path/to/my/app/?.lua'

local app = require('app.init');
app.start()
```

And the nginx config is

```
rewrite_by_lua_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/start.lua;
```

If I were to copy/paste the metric code into `start.lua`, then the metric is updated every time. Why is this?!

**Update**

I noticed this in the error logs:

```
2018/05/23 10:02:07 [error] 24483#0: *6 attempt to send data on a closed socket: u:some-hex, c:some-hex, client: 123.12.0.123, server: *.my-url.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "my.my-url.com"
```

This happens on the 2nd request to the nginx; the first time after restart, this is all fine ...

**Update 2**

This happens only if I have a `metrics` file and `require` it in my other. So if I instantiate the `resty_dogstatsd` client inside the main lua file, then everything is fine ...

Comment: First of all, if you have a `/app/init.lua` file, you can usually just `require 'app'`. If this doesn't work, try adding `;/path/?/init.lua` instead and it should work with just `'app'` [[read more](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers)]. Also, you *can* (but don't have to) drop the `()` braces when the only argument is a table literal: `function{table = "this is a table"}`

Comment: From what I get, you don't mention where you call the metric code from. My best guess is: you have code-cache enabled and run the code in some file that you `require` and expect it to run each time it's `require`d? Something similar happened to me once; `require` runs a file only once and caches its result. See if that's the source of your problem. Again, [this section](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers) in the docs is relevant and I suggest you read it carefully.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer I updated my question with an error i noticed in the logs